# Quick questions for marketplace magento2

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I have few questions related to posting extension to marketplace. I have listed all the questions below:

1. How can we submit two extension together in one folder as we do have support extension with our main extension?
2. Why extension taking so much time in technical review?
3. Why extension get reject by telling like "Business Review" fail.
   What will be the reason?

We just wanted to know about process of the submitting marketplace.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can submit your shared package, your own library, separately from all your extensions. On https://developer.magento.com/ in packages section, you may create your shared package. So, in this case, when you will upload you extension, you must add your library name to require section in composer.json file of your extension. Also we highly recommend to upload shared library first, and than Installation checker can install all necessary dependencies.
2. The main reason is that some of our steps in technical check are manual (for now). Such as QA and Copy Past Detector (CPD). So all of them are processing according to queue. Currently we are working to optimize this process, to add more automation here.
3. As I know this step checks if the functionality of your extension is unique. It means if Marketplace already have extensions with the same functionality or such functionality is present in Magento Platform - your extension will be rejected. Try to make your extension unique.

Answer (score 11):

The first thing you should do is to login on http://marketplace.magento.com and update the new developer profile with your developer or company information. After that the following steps have to be done in order to successfully submit an extensions:

1. Upload the .zip package of your module to the Marketplace and provide all necessary information.
       Go to your uploaded extensions https://developer.magento.com/extension/extension/list/
       Click on Add Extension
2. Submit the extension for technical review whereas the first part is automated code analysis (based on phpcs) and the second part is manual review by Magento.

   Once your extension is submitted to review it gets the following status

   **Marketplace Review**

   If review was successful you get an email informing you about that. Our first submission took 6 weeks, but to be fair, we submitted the extension right after marketplace launch. The Magento review team did get a lot of
   extensions for review so it took so much time. But Magento already said that they want to reduce the maximum review time to 2 weeks.
3. During or after the technical review you can provide necessary marketing information in order to promote the extension properly. Here you can add descriptions, screenshots, pricing, videos etc. The following status is telling you that you can update product information:

   **Ready for Review Marketing**
4. After successful technical review you can submit your extension for marketing review as Magento wants to ensure unique brand appearance:

   **In Marketing Review**
5. After successful marketing review the extension immediately gets published to the Marketplace.

This video can help you to understand more : https://vimeo.com/156767727

> **NOTE :** Also prepare proper documentation for description part in
>   marketplace. It will help you to approve your extension fast.

You should consider following links while creating an extension :

**Coding Standards** : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/bk-coding-standards.html

**Magento 2 Marketplace Upload Validation Tool (Quick Note) :** [https://alankent.me/2016/02/01/magento-2-marketplace-upload-validation-tool-quick-note/](http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/getting-started/guidelines.html)

**Submission Guidelines :** http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/getting-started/guidelines.html

This may helpful to you.

Comment: Nice answer with good video in details explanation. :)